# Restart bind service when killed by system automatically in android

Tags: android

I'm using a Service to perform a background task, when I start it by startService () and put it in the onStartCommand () method START_STICKY; It restarts whenever the system forces the application to close. But when I start this same service using BindService () it does not automatically restarta the service.

Answer (score 0):

Service bound is only for the lifetime of the application. It exists until the application closes or unbind is called on it.

[See the android documentation for details](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: So, if the application is forcibly closed by the system, can not it restart by itself as when started by startService ()?

Comment: It can. It now depends on which context you call startService from.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Because this service I use to track the distance a user walks through, and during a certain moment in my activity I need to stop the tracking and take the information of the distance traveled and start again, or I need to communicate with the service, but if the Dying activity the service is dying when I'm using bindService ().